# Deleting all content between {} brackets in beautifulSoup output

Tags: beautifulsoup

I would like to parse text form html pages. Some pages return the text, but also some text and characters between `{}` which I do not want.

I tried:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

art = soup.find_all('p')
for clean in art: 
    x = clean.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    x = re.sub("([{]).*?([}])", "\g<1>\g<2>", x)
    print(x.strip())
```

But no cigar...

Comment: Hmmmm... I think I also need some guidance on how to properly compose a question...

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a quicker response.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) input text and expected output?